# Vue.js - directive to convert markdown code to html

Tags: vue.js

I have a very simple directive like so in my sample Vue app:

```
import habiticaMarkdown from 'habitica-markdown';

export default function markdown (el ) {
  console.log(el.innerHTML);
  if ( el.innerHTML !== '' ) {
    el.innerHTML = habiticaMarkdown.render(String(el.innerHTML));
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = '';
  }

  el.classList.add('markdown');
}
```

I use this compoenent in my main app file like so::

```
<div v-markdown >
        ### I am lala
</div>
```

And then the javascript code in my app.vue looks like so:

```
import markdown from './directives/markdown.js';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  directives : {
    markdown
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
```

What i see rendered to my browser is  `### I am lala` , when what i actually would like is this to be converted to an  , not just render my markdown code as is , how do i convert markdown code in my main app.vue file to html then ?

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your directive definition. Are you sure it actually runs?

Comment: @bernie yes it does run , can you point out to me what you think is actually missing ? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm I'm stumped then. My understanding was that directives work through the hook functions defined here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions Yet your code doesn't seem to use them. Is the `markdown` class added to your element?